# Can't access configuration page of TP-Link network expander (TP-AV500)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, fritzbox

Probably not the best place to ask, but I need help very badly.

So, we bought this TP-Link AV500 to expand our network, but I can't access the configuration page. It should be found under http://tplinkplclogin.net but it redirects me to a page saying:

> Trying to Configure the Powerline Extender?
>
> It looks like you may have run into an issue
>
> If you're connecting to the Router directly, you will be unable to access >the Powerline Extender's management page by using http://tplinkplclogin.net

and it also says that I am not connected to the repeater, but to the main router (Fritz!Box) and that is not true.

And something that's also strange is that the devices in the expander network has a similar ip as in the router network.

For example my laptop in the router network: 192.168.0.28
and in the expander network: 192.168.0.40

The two Expander devices don't even have an ip.

How can I get to the configuration page?
And I cant use the CD, because i dont have a CD drive.

Comment: for anyone reading. i realized my browser had saved the link as starting with https:// (which it also emits from the url view) i realized it needs to begin with http:// after i got it working in another browser. hope that helps anyone who may have had the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I had the same issue but solved it both on the AV500 and AV600,the urls like this that TP-Link tell you to use http://tplinkplc.net rarely work because that url and even TP-Links software utilities are looking for a specific internal IP address for your extenders but your routers DHCP didn't assign that IP address.

You need to do is find the internal IP address for your extender and ideally set it to stick to a specific IP address.

**Solution**

1. After you have your Powerline connection sorted, connect into the extender/expander via an Ethernet cable.
2. Download the **Powerline Scan Utility** from TP-Link's website (The scan utility is all you need, don't worry about the proper utility).

Make sure you get the Scan Utility for your hardware version, you can see that on the back of the extender plug. You're router won't always show you the devices for some reason hence why this tool is mentioned.

3. Then when you launch that scan tool it will show you the internal IP address that you're device has been assigned and there will be a connect button, press that and login with admin/admin.
4. Once inside go to the Network tool, change the IP address to something you want. Then copy the MAC address displayed into you're router and reserve that to the same IP address in the router.

   **Tips:**
5. Change the admin password on the TP-Link extender, its admin/admin by default.
6. You can then also set it to mirror your routers SSID by changing the SSID name and password to that of your main router and then setting the security protocol to WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK , then press the reboot link.
7. You can also enable a temporary guest-ssid in these settings if you have a new TP-Link device, then you can prevent connected devices from being able to access admin pages on your router and powerlines.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the kits being sold don't have a cd.  I was able to download the utility from TP-Link based on the model (WPA 4220 Extender version 1 in my case).  Once I installed that utility on my pc it came up with the installed plc network and the wifi extenders had a "website" popout that brought up the browser admin admin configuration tool.  At that point I could note the ip address for each in my browser.  In my case they were http://192.168.0.225/  and  http://192.168.0.9/ which then worked directly without the TP-Link utility.

Answer (score 0):

#### I can't access the configuration page. It should be found under tplinkplclogin.net

> I am not connected to the repeater, but to the main router (Fritz!Box).

You should connect directly to the repeater with an Ethernet cable and configure from there:

> **3.1.1 For Wired Connection**
>
> If your computer is connected to the extender via Ethernet cable, you
>   can log in the extender by following the steps below:
>
> 1. Insert the TP-LINK Resource CD into the CD-ROM drive. The following screen will appear. Select model TL-WPA4220 and then choose Management
>      Utility from the drop-down menu.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Find the model to be configured and click Connect to log in the Web-based management utility.
>
>    [image]

Source [300Mbps AV500 WiFi Powerline Extender](http://static.tp-link.com/resources/document/TL-WPA4220KIT(EU_V1_User_Guid.pdf)

Comment: Ah, there was a misunderstanding. I meant that the page says that i am not connected to the expander. But i am indeed. And i dont have a CD Drive so i cant use the CD

Comment: @plankins Then you should edit and clarify your question :/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

- I searched my model here: https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/
- In my case it was AV600: https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/tl-wpa4220t-kit/
- By default you have WiFi enabled, so you can **download the App Store and Google Play app** to access it:
- I disabled WiFi for on the PLC, so to access it by Ethernet cable, download the **Utility for Windows or Mac**. Unfortunately the Utility **crashed in my Mac**, but I found a beta version here: https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/161045

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Configuring older WPA4220 v1 devices from newer versions of MacOS is a challenge.  I found a way to discover the IP address of a WPA4220 v1 device.  Create a small network consisting of a TL-WPA4220, a TL-PA4010, and a router:

iMac  --(wifi)-- WPA4220  <--->  TL-PA4010  <--->  router  ---->  internet

First run the "IP Scanner" app on the iMac; the WPA4220 most likely will not show up.

But then run tpPLC on the iMac; that should find and display both the WPA4220 and PA4010 devices.

Now look at the IP Scanner display again; you should see an entry "unidentified device"  with an IP address.

Now use the IP address to login with a browser.